# typescript unknown arrow syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript

Reading some TS code and came across the following:

```
  private onChange : ( value : string ) => void;
```

I get it that we have a private onchange variable which is an object with a property that is a string (correct me if I'm wrong plz). However, what is the `=>`?

I thought that in typescript return type of a function was declared like this:

```
function add(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x + y;
}
```

Is it just ES6 arrow function syntax stating that function will return void or something else?

Comment: That's a function type. So it means that the `onChange` field holds a function which accepts a string as its parameter and returns void. Read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

Comment: '=>' is it a ES6 ...(value:string) => void same as function(value){return void}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(value : string ) => void` is a function type, a function accepting a `string` parameter and returning `void`. The class declares a field `onChange` of this type. So we could do things like :

```
this.onChange = function (value) { console.log(value); };
this.onChange = (value) => { console.log(value); };
this.onChange("");
```

You are right the return type of a function declaration is introduced with `:`, bot for function types it is introduced with `=>`